# The boundary of the transversal pre-image of a submanifold with boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, transversality

A similar question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4407834/the-transversal-pre-image-of-a-manifold-with-boundary) without answer.

Let $M, N$ be smooth manifolds such that $\partial N=\varnothing$. Let $A$ be a smoothly embedded submanifold of $N$ such that $\partial A\neq \varnothing$. Suppose, $f\colon M\to N$ be a smooth map with $f\pitchfork A,\ f\pitchfork \partial A$. In case $\partial M\neq \varnothing$, we also assume that the restriction $f\big|\partial M\to N$ is transverse to $A$.

> Is it true that $f^{-1}(A)$ is a smoothly embedded submanifold of $M$
> with $$\partial f^{-1}(A)=\begin{cases}f^{-1}(\partial A)&\text{ if
>  }\partial M=\varnothing,\\ \big(f^{-1}(A)\cap \partial M\big)\cup
>  f^{-1}(\partial A) &\text{ if }\partial M\neq
>  \varnothing.\end{cases}$$

Comment: This isn't quite true, since the pre-image may no longer be a manifold with boundary (when $M$ and $A$ have boundary).  For example, it can be a manifold with cubical corners.